# How to deform multiple mesh objects with one manipulator?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, armature, linked-data

Simply put:

I'd like to be able to manipulate the shape of more than one side by side object at a time. Like a rubicks cube reshape all the cubes with one manipulator.

Thank you

Further discribed:

How can I take two objects **side by side** and reshape them together (one or both), as they reshape together their borders are kept side by side.
So the end result is still two objects side by side but now they are both or one have a different shape.

Comment: Could you claify if you are talking about keeping stitched the faces or the borders (so the edges)? Maybe add two a screenshots, one with the starting situation and one with the wanted result.

Comment: Would an explanation of how to make a Rubik's Cube help?  If that's not what you are trying to make you could try to apply the same principles to your application.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with an armature.

Here a simple Rubik's cube like mesh object parented to an armature.

The second cube is a linked duplicate.

[image: Rubick's cube objects controlled by a single armature]

The cube blocks on the face that rotate have been assigned to a vertex group, as we can verify in Weight Paint Mode.

[image: Rubick's cube weight paint]

After creating your armature make sure the bone is in the right place and has no rotation issues. You can lock the transforms so it doesn't rotate in undesired ways.

[image: Lock bone transforms]

When parenting the cube to the armature Set Parent to "Armature Deform with Empty Groups".

[image: Parenting the cube to the armature]

Ensure that the groups and bones have matching names.

[image: Armature Modifier - note the bone group name]

Here's the .blend from the screen shots in case I forgot to explain anything:

[image]